# Initialization of a large const array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Are there anyway to initialize a large const array without typing every single elements within it, for instance:

trying to create a array:

```
const double A[1000] = {1.0/1, 1.0/2, 1.0/3,...,1.0/1000};
```

It's easy to do with a loop.

Comment: For this particulat thing, I'd say `const double A[1000] = {1, 0 };` would do. But you probably mean `1/2.0` or `1.0/2`, etc. In which case you'll have to do the hard work yourself. Or do some really weird magic with #includes in #if statements.

Comment: @Mats Petersson Can you explain how to use macro to do that? thanks.

Comment: If `A` is not global a variable. then you can first create an array `A` in loop then pass it to `function(const double* A)` and now in `function(const double* A){ // A[i]  is constant }` ..declaration is not possible. And either Joe's answer is best idea.

Comment: You can use const_cast to remove const modifier from the variable and then use an ordinary function to initialize it.

Comment: If you don't mind getting an std::array instead of a C array, C++11 has fancy solutions for you.

Comment: @Spook: No you can't; modifying a const object gives undefined behaviour. In particular, it may well be placed in read-only memory,  giving a protection fault if you try to modify it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If so, why does the const_cast operator exist? Microsoft does not seem to care about that rule in the example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Spook: It exists so you can modify a non-const object when you only have a const pointer/reference to it. In the example you show, the object `X` is not `const`, but in the `const` member function `this` has type `const CCTest*`, and so needs a `const_cast` in order to modify the object. If `X` were `const`, then the program would have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

If it really has to be const and you have 1000 different values write some kiddy app/script to spit it out as a header file and prevent your typing! That gives you an easy way to modify the whole array initialisation later if need be too.

Comment: ... well, thats maybe a solution.

Comment: Not ideal I know, but writing code that writes code is something we shy away from too much these days. It can help in some circumstances!

Answer (score 3):

You can use boost's preprocessor library for this:

Your main file:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>


const double A[1000] = {
#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_LIMITS (0, 9)
#define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1 "toplevel.hpp"
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()
};
```

File `"toplevel.hpp"`:

```
#define ENUMERATE(z, i, data) 1.0 / (BOOST_PP_ITERATION() * 100 + i)

BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(BOOST_PP_ITERATION()) BOOST_PP_ENUM(100, ENUMERATE, %%)

#undef ENUMERATE
```

It works by including "toplevel.hpp" ten times in a row, with `BOOST_PP_ITERATION()` expanding to 0, 1, .. 9 in each iteration (0 and 9 come from `BOOST_PP_ITERATION_LIMITS`).

`BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF()` produces a comma if the argument is nonzero.

`BOOST_PP_ENUM()` expands the macro (`ENUMERATE` in this case) 100 times, with `i` getting the values 0 to 99 (based on argument `100`).

**EDIT**

Added explanation and also removed superfluous `BOOST_PP_OR()`.

**EDIT 2**

This two-stage iteration (file and macro within it) has to be used because most iteration schemes in boost::preprocessor are limited to max. 256 iterations (as stored in various `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_*` macros).

It could also be done using a nested BOOST_PP_ENUM(), without file iteration.

Comment: You probably want to explain why something that complicated is needed, as opposed to say BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(1000, 1./) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of pointers to const char, that way you could initialize them at run-time using **new** with a loop.

Otherwise, I don't believe there is a way. You could either just go ahead and initialize it manually in the header file, or strip it of it's `const` status.If it is not initialized at compile time, the compiler complains about not initializing a `const` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I would probably write a small program to do this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{ 
    printf("1/%d.0, ", i);
    if(i % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
}
```

I thought you could do this with macros, and I'm pretty sure it CAN be done, but I can't make it work right now. I'll come back if I get it working.